# Spring boot dont see a mustache template

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, mustache

I've very simple application on Spring boot. It's just one controller and mustache template.

```
package io.github.aleksejshherbak.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And the template is just simple markup

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Person keeper</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I've installed mustache with the help of gradle. My build file is

```
plugins {
id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building an application
    id 'application'


    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.6.RELEASE'
}

mainClassName = 'io.github.aleksejshherbak.App'

group 'io.github'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.spullara.mustache.java/compiler
    compile group: 'com.github.spullara.mustache.java', name: 'compiler', version: '0.8.9'
}
```

The structure of the project is on the following picture
[image]

But when I start it and type in my browser `localhost:8080/` I have 404 error. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add to dependency:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache'
```

And configure `application.properties` for mustache:

```
spring.mustache.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.mustache.suffix=.mustache
```